# Why is/was JavaScript checking in HTML in VS Code gone circa March 2016?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Take the following sample of HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

  var myArr = ['thing1' thing2'];

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're perceptive, you'll notice that I forgot to put a comma between the two array values inside of the script. This will, of course, cause any browser to fail to parse it and the whole script tag will not run. In previous versions of Code, this would be noted with a red underline, but it seems like in recent versions support has moved to plugins. They recommend installing the JSHint plugin to catch some issues, but I have a .jshintrc file in my project directory, with very few entries (to try to use mostly defaults) and while it catches "recommendations", it's still not catching actual syntax issues that break the scripts entirely. I'm also not sure it's doing anything for JavaScript it sees inside of a `<script>` tag (which I currently use to do quick tests or examples of features). It highlights keywords, but doesn't check syntax or anything.

Is there any configuration I can apply to Code, or my project, to get back this behavior?

Comment: Closevoter: From [asking](/help/on-topic): *"if your question generally covers... **software tools commonly used by programmers** ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"* Visual Studio Code would be such a tool, so the question is on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catching of actual syntax issues has been delegated to the [Salsa](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Salsa) interpreter within Visual Studio. Maybe this is a bug? However, for the other point you made about quick-checking code within script tags, as of the [v0.10.10 Feb 2016 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vfebruary):

> There is no longer support for IntelliSense in script sections inside HTML documents.

Comment: salsa link is dead and a proper save in web.archive.org does not exist.